# UPDATE with too much values at IN state takes too long

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, where

I have the next query:

```
UPDATE plates_owners SET deleted=1 WHERE plate_id=4748 AND branch_id IN
(23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,42,43,46,47,48,64,79,82,83,102,103,130,169,209,218,220,221,222,223,224,226,231,232)
```

Here is my `plates_owners` structure:

```
plate_id     | int(11) unsigned | PRI
branch_id    | int(11) unsigned | PRI
show_app     | int(1) unsigned  |
deleted      | int(1) unsigned  |
app_disabled | int(1) unsigned  |
modified     | timestamp        |
```

This query takes over 50 seconds to execute, is there anyway to optimize it?

PS: The less values I add to the IN statement the faster the query becomes

Comment: do you have any indexes on (plate_id,branch_id) (using both columns)? What does `PRI` mean in your "structure of the table"? Can you give a SQL command how you created the table?

Comment: How many rows in the table?  How many have `deleted=1`?

Comment: Which order are the columns in the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE plate_owners` to avoid questions like this.  What version of MySQL?  Things changed recently.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating yourself a [temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html), inserting your branch numbers into it, and then performing the [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) using a [JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/), like so:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE branch_numbers 
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT branch_numbers (id)
VALUES (23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36)
      ,(37),(38),(39),(40),(42),(43),(46),(47),(48),(64),(79),(82),(83),(102)
      ,(103),(130),(169),(209),(218),(220),(221),(222),(223),(224),(226),(231)
      ,(232);

UPDATE plates_owners 
 INNER JOIN branch_numbers ON plates_owners.branch_id = branch_numbers.id
   SET deleted=1 
 WHERE plate_id=4748;

DROP TABLE branch_numbers;
```

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE branch_numbers (branch_id INT NOT NULL, plate_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 4748,  PRIMARY KEY(plate_id, branch_id) );` is more safe - both indices will match fully.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE plates_owners
SET deleted=1 
WHERE plate_id=4748
  AND FIND_IN_SET(
         branch_id,
         (23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,42,43,46,47,48,64,79,82,83,102,103,130,169,209,218,220,221,222,223,224,226,231,232)
      ) > 0
```

Comment: The second argument needs to be a string, and without the parens.